# Yum Install is taking forever to read default repositories in Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos, redhat, amazon-linux

```
[root@ip-172-31-27-95 rpm]# yum -d 10 install munin-node
Loading "priorities" plugin
Loading "update-motd" plugin
Loading "upgrade-helper" plugin
Config time: 0.007
Yum version: 3.4.3
rpmdb time: 0.000
Setting up Package Sacks
amzn-main/latest                                                                                                                                                                 
| 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-main/latest/group                                                                                                                                                               
|  35 kB     00:00     
amzn-main/latest/primary_db                                                                                                                                                          
| 3.6 MB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                                                                                                                                                  
| 2.3 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest/group                                                                                                                                                            
|  35 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest/updateinfo                                                                                                                                                       
| 384 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest/primary_db                                                                                                                                                       
| 167 kB     00:00     
pkgsack time: 0.767
```

I'm trying to install `munin-node` into my Amazon Linux. Unfortunately every time I run `yum install munin-node`, it'll get stuck on reading the repositories as shown in the snippet above.

I already tried the following troubleshooting:

1. Kill yum process
2. `rpm --rebuilddb`
3. `rm /var/run/yum.pid`
4. `yum clean all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem so I checked for any shared file lock using:
`lslocks`
 
and found out that 3 processes where acquiring the same system lock files
`/var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock`

it was:

1. *`rpm`*
2. *`yum`*
3. *`package-cleanup`*

so I deleted the file:
**`sudo rm /var/lib/rpm/.dbenv.lock`**

tried to install again and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all I needed was to reboot the server and `yum install` works fine again. Not sure what went wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by disabling the repo directly. On my case were ius.repo and collaboraoffice.com_repos_CollaboraOnline_CODE-centos7.repo which were causing the yum execution took so long to finish.

So, using vim editor I edited the .repo file directly, like so:

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/ius.repo
```

then set

```
enabled=1
```

to

```
enabled=0
```

And I have disabled the collaboraoffice.com_repos_CollaboraOnline_CODE-centos7.repo the same way like above.

After that, I executed

```
yum update
```

And it turns out OK.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: tried it and did not work for me (unfortunately)...